# [LUA]Counting numbers and operators in a string

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to create a basic calculator.I'm taking the user commands as a string.For instance consider the input as **5+3-2/5** in this string i need to count how many numbers and operators are here.So,what could be the solution to this?

Comment: How does counting help you in writing a calculator?

Comment: I know my algorithm isn't efficient but worth a try anyway thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` returns the number of substitutions made. So try this code:

```
s="5+3-2/5"

function count(s,p)
    local _,n=s:gsub(p," ")
    return n
end

print(count(s,"%d+"))
print(count(s,"[+%-*/]"))
```

The code assumes that numbers are integers.

Comment: Hint: replace `%d+` with `[%d.,]+` to count non-ints too.